# MS Excel: Is it possible to "freeze" cells?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following issue:

I have feature recommendations for specific types of software packages listed on a picklist.

On another sheet I enter several software packages and when I start a new row with a nee software package, this sheet should tell me which features are possible or recommended for the type of software package I have chosen for my new package.

This is done with a VLOOKUP which has its matrix on the picklist and this works fine.

**However in case the recommendations change on the picklist for future software packages I have a problem.** Because if i change the recommendations on the picklist, the data get changed also for packages I have entered in the past however the new changes should only apply for packages entered in the future.

A solution would be that I could "freeze" rows where I have entered past packages via a Button or something like this which is positioned on the right side of every row, which makes those rows only hold the values but removes the VLOOKUP formula.

I could also copy the values of a row I want to freeze in the same row and click on the "Values only" command, which removes the formula but keeps the values but I just wanted to know if there is some sort of convinient function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a simple macro to do so like:

```
Sub pastevalues()


 On Error Resume Next
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

I entered the error ignorance for cases when you paste without copying before.
You can add a short cut to the macro. This way if you are using the ctrl+v to paste make anew shortcut like ctrl+q to paste special values.